# how the two external antennas in a wifi range extender work

Tags: wireless-networking, antenna, wireless-extender

I was just wondering, in a wifi range extender with two positionable external antennas, how the antennas work, for example, are they used only to resend the wifi signal or they are used to receive from the router as well, and are they working in tandem, or one is for downloading and the other for uploading? I hope I've expressed clearly the question, thank you in advance for your reply, Bruno

Comment: It depends on the hardware, starting with the chipset in how many antennae and what configuration(s) it supports. On top of that there's software, the chipset's driver and firmware and the and the repeater's OS.